# Excel Tables VBA: Trying to select rows based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

I am a beginner. I have been trying to teach myself VBA and researching this question for two weeks, including reviewing all the relevant answers on this forum. I give up!

I am trying to loop through the rows of a table to select a table row based on the content of one of the row's cells (naming a particular column). I want to use the name of the table column. But something is wrong with my "If ... Then" statement. I get errors with every attempt. Right now I get a compile error "Expected Then or Go To," with the period before Value highlighted. But I have a feeling that if I fixed that error there would be another one right behind it. What am I getting wrong, besides trying to learn this on my own? ;>)

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
       For x = 1 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count
           If (Range("Table1[Status]")).Value = "Completed"
               'I can't seem to find the right statement to put between If and .Value!
               Rows(x).Select
           End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `If (Range("Table1[Status]")).Value = "Completed"` to `If (Range("Table1[Status]")).Value = "Completed" then`. That would fix that issue, the next concept is what you want to do after identifying the row/s. The current .select would just be superceded by the next .select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `If (Range("Table1[Status]")).Value = "Completed"` to `If (Range("Table1[Status]").Value) = "Completed" Then`. Your `.Value` just needed to be put in the brackets. I would also highly suggest looking into the [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) add-in for VBA. It has an Auto Indenter so your code always looks in order.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    Dim myRange As Range

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    For x = 1 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count
        If tbl.DataBodyRange(x, Range("Table1[Status]").Column) = "Completed" Then
            If myRange Is Nothing Then
                Set myRange = tbl.ListRows(x).Range
            Else
                Set myRange = Union(myRange, tbl.ListRows(x).Range)
            End If
        End If
    Next x
    myRange.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Berticus, but now I get Error 13, Type Mismatch ... highlighting the If  Then statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: @B.Wildered My bad. That's what I get for not testing the code. See my edit and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hello Berticus, I'm sorry to keep bugging you. I really appreciate your help. First, the good part: This one actually runs and selects something! You got me further than I have been in two weeks! However, 1)It selects only one row 2)It does not select a row with the value of "Completed" and 3)It selects the row for the whole sheet, rather than just the row inside the table. Any chance you can help?

Comment: @B.Wildered No worries it's what were here for! 1) Does this mean you want multiple rows selected when it's done running? 2) Did you include the `Rows(x + 1).Select` in the new code? 3) When you say row do you only want it to select the individual cell in the table or select across JUST the table?

Comment: Berticus, when it is finished running I would like to have *all* the rows selected where they contain "Completed" in the column "Status." And, I would like the selection to run across *just* the table. To your question about Rows(x + 1).Select, the answer is yes. Thanks so much! I tried some alternatives myself but none of them worked.

Comment: OH MY GOSH, Berticus! It works! It works! You are AWESOME! I promise to honor your assistance by studying what you did!

Comment: @B.Wildered Glad to help! Let me know if anything doesn't make sense. If this answers your question please consider marking it as accepted (Green check mark).